# Unable to resolve module react-native-blob-util

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler, xcode13.3

I'm facing this issue , when we run yarn IOS project - it is building successfully and and installing on simulator ,

while loading, metro bundler stops at some point and throws below error.

[image]

Tried below steps also, no luck.

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Please lete me know how i can resolve this issue.

env : MacBook Pro M1 , RN version - 0.61.5 , Xcode - 13

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the missing dependency:

### Using npm

```
npm install react-native-blob-util --save
```

### or using yarn:

```
yarn add react-native-blob-util
```

Answer (score 0):

rn-fetch-blob and react-native blob util can't work together.remove rn-fetch-blob and use react-native blob util instead of this.